# How to check whether MOD drive is working in Linux based system

Tags: linux

I have an issue with the Linux based computer which belongs to Hitachi MRI Medical Equipment. We replaced the MOD drive(not CD or DVD) which was used to read MOD disks. After replacing the Drive I am not getting any response from the OS. I wanted to know how to check whether new MOD drive is operational in the Linux based system. I believe it will be mounted similar to a CDROM or DVD.

The Linux running in the computer is kind of some secure console but I can access to terminal while booting. I don't know whether I have root access or not.

Any Ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any clue as to what linux is running on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

More information is needed, but what I suggest you to do is monitoring the MOD disk through the `udev` utility:

1. Launch the below command:

   ```
   udevadm monitor --property --udev
   ```
2. While the command is running, try to plugin your disk.
3. Check if new lines are written to the output.
4. If so, then get the DEVNAME attribute.
5. Execute the below command and look to the DEVNAME previously shown to get the
   block device name related to the MOD:

   ```
   blkid
   ```
6. Mount it like this:

   ```
   mkdir /mnt/mod
   mount <DEVNAME> /mnt/mod
   ```

If no output is generated during the 2nd step, then the MOD reader or the disk itself may be defective, because the kernel is unable to recognize it.